# Python Tools - Unable to run commands in interpreter

Tags: django, visual-studio, django-south, ptvs

I'm trying to get south working in my Visual Studio environment but I can't seem any of the commands shown in the tutorial to work like `manage.py schemamigration movies --initial` that will just show the following error

```
  File "<stdin>", line 1
    manage.py schemamigration movies --initial
                            ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

I've tried using `Django Shell`, `Validate Django App...`, `Django Sync DB...` options from the project context menu to open the interpreter and `Tools > Python Tools > Python 64-bit 2.7 Interactive` but neither of those worked.

I'm using Visual Studio Ultimate 2013 Preview with Python Tools version 2.0.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This command is something that you should type in the Windows command prompt, not in a Python source file or Interactive window (aka REPL) - the latter are for Python code, which this isn't.

Comment: How do you open the command prompt? I'll have to user normal cmd or there's a shortcut in vs2013?

Comment: In the most general case, yes - but also see [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18622489/111335) and [this](https://pytools.codeplex.com/workitem/1888).