# How to run Django manage.py commands in Python Tools for Visual Studio?

Tags: python, django, ptvs

Development using Django requires running manage.py commands once in a while. I'm using Python Tools for Visual Studio (PTVS) with VS 2015 community ed. Some manage.py commands (like syncdb) are accessible from the menu when a project is created using PTVS's Django template (but not when you use a generic python project and install django using "Install Python package..."), but for others you have to do it the usual way. It seems a waste of time opening a command prompt, changing directory, activating virtualenv and going back to the manage.py's dir - just to execute one command.

I noticed that in JetBrains PyCharm it is possible to [run Django manage.py utility from within the IDE](https://www.jetbrains.com/pycharm/help/running-tasks-of-manage-py-utility.html). Is there a similar feature in Python Tools? Or is it possible to create a shortcut in VS for that?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found an answer to this question myself, turns out [it was asked before](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18084028/how-to-run-commands-from-within-visual-studio-ptvs/18622489#18622489).
And the answer is no, there is no such feature in PTVS. Here is [a disscussion of this issue](https://pytools.codeplex.com/workitem/1888) in the PTVS bug tracker. As an alternative, [console launching extension](https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/1460ab21-75be-49d0-900f-dfd538321424) could be used.